# How to handle validation for Relationship PK and FK in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I have 2 table name `tblGroup` and `tblSubGroup` and `tblGroup` has `GroupId` which is primary and `tblSubGroup` has `Groupid` which is foreign key.
Below are the model generated for them

**tblGroup Model**

```
public partial class tblGroup
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblGroup()
    {
        this.tblSubGroups = new HashSet<tblSubGroup>();
    }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Group Name is Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblSubGroup> tblSubGroups { get; set; }
}
```

**tblSubGroup Model**

```
 public partial class tblSubGroup
{
    public int SubGroupID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "tblGroup")]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "SubGroup Name is Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual tblGroup tblGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Now on deleting record of From `GroupTable` it is giving issue. Instead I need to `validate` a message that "This record is bind with another table or entity. So it cannot be deleted". I need to show this kind of message.

**As I am new I don't know this things is possible or not**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to verify with the database you move this type of validation to the server.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Group group)
{
    var grp = db.Group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == group.Id);

    if (HasSubGroups(grp))
    {
        ModelState.AddError("DeleteValidation", "Cannot delete while sub-groups exists");
        return View(group);
    }

    // delete normally ... 
}
```

Then you could display the errors on the view in several ways. The simplest is just to show the collection.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Comment: Is this not possible from model side?

Comment: You could pre-validate the model and hide the delete action. But you still should validate on the server. In any case, the database would complain because of the FK relationship.

Comment: Can I know how to implement HasSubGroups?

Comment: by default it is generating  private bool HasSubGroups(tblGroup grp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: It's just a helper method (possibly on the controller class). You just count the attached entities. If you have lots of business validations you could collect these into a new class.